# How do I select text with 3 last characters removed with ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xhtml

I need to show text on a webpage but need to cut 3 last characters:
Python%22 becomes --> Python

I tried substring() but it does not seem to work properly.
Help will be appreciated!

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="MainData">
        <div id="dataRows">
          {
            data.map(obj => {
              return (
                <div key={obj.g_prof_url}>
                  **
                  // Here I need to "print" Python not Python%22
                  <p>{obj.g_prof_name.substring(0,-3)}</p>
                  **
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.slice` method which works on strings, example:

```
obj.g_prof_name.slice(0,obj.g_prof_name.length-3)
```

this method will get you the substring from char with index 0 to the end of string - 3 index

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
obj.g_prof_name.substring(0, obj.g_prof_name.length - 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second argument have to be positive - it's the index of the first character to exclude from the returned substring.

try this -

```
<p>{obj.g_prof_name.substring(0, obj.g_prof_name.length - 3)}</p>
```